# opencart 1.5.6.4: session_start() gets "no such file" error

Tags: php, session, opencart

My opencart 1.5.6.4 [website](https://newyorkliquorgiftshop.com/admin/) had been working well until several weeks ago I got this error:

> Warning: session_start():
> open(/home/content/55/5307955/tmp/sess_qphb8rav2kmt5kavptqh1mik06,
> O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in
> /home/content/55/5307955/html/system/library/session.php on line 12
>
> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter -
> headers already sent (output started at
> /home/content/55/5307955/html/admin/index.php:89) in
> /home/content/55/5307955/html/system/library/session.php on line 12

As a front-end developer, I am not very familiar with PHP. The only thing I can do is to check the "tmp" folder's permisson, and it is 0705 which I think is good. I went ahead and changed it to 0777 but it didn't work. Can anyone show me where to start to solve this problem?

P.S. I didn't do anything to the website, but there was something abnormal when it stopped working: The document root was changed somehow. Currently it is "/home/content/55/5307955/html" but it was not. When the problem got up for the first time, my website just showed some error message like it can't find the application under "/home/content/55/5307955/html" folder, I had to manually change the document root settings in both `config.php` files to match this folder - I have to emphasise here that before this my website worked well.

After the change the website could be open but it has been with the above error message and I can't login to dashboard. I contacted Godaddy asking them why and when my document root was changed but they said there was no change, unhelpful as always.

Comment: While I'd never use GoDaddy, I have some sympathy for web hosts. They will often get support calls that are effectively requests to debug a program, and that is way out of scope for a free support channel.

Comment: The error "Cannot send session cache limiter" is caused by the first one. Resolve the first one and the second one will go away. For the first one, try clearing your cookies?

Comment: I tried using different computers and browsers so I dont think the problem is related to cookie.

Comment: OK. How about uploading a little session test script, like `<?php session_start(); $val = isset($_SESSION['x']) ? $_SESSION['x'] : 0; $_SESSION['x']++; echo $_SESSION['x']; ?>`. Does that work on its own?

Comment: I did. I tried create a new file with `session_start()`, which triggers the same problem. I have done reading some basics about Session, I don't understand why session_start() would try to open a file, which doesn't exist in my case. Actually I am about to start a new question asking this.

Comment: Another question [probably isn't necessary](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=session+O_RDWR+failed%3A+No+such+file+or+directory). When you say you created a new file, do you mean a completely stand-alone script, which does not run any OpenCart code? If so, I wonder if it is your `php.ini` settings, which I believe GoDaddy does allow you to change.

Comment: yes it is a stand-alone file with only 1 line - session_start(). So what setting  should I look into in php.ini?

Comment: wait I think I found where the problem could be. The `tmp` folder is not under my document root, insteadly it is at the same level with my document root, which I don't have access. Now the question is, why `session_start()` would try to write things into that folder? I've gone through opencart's `config.php` file, but there seems to be no setting about where the temporary folder should be.

Comment: No, don't put it in your document root - it is dangerous to have your `tmp` folder readable by the web server. If that were to be used by your sessions, then in theory that means your sessions could be intercepted by anyone who knew where to look, and/or how to guess at the random session file string.